# JS having variable update in for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to JavaScript and coding in general, and i'm running into a problem with for-loop. I tell the loop to repeat 5 times, and the loop is supposed to halve the given number(200) 5 times, resulting in 6.25. Currently it halves the 200 5 times, but I can't figure out how to save the number in variable after each loop correctly, so it just repeats 200/2 = 100, 200/2 = 100, 200/2 = 100, 200/2 = 100, 200/2 = 100.

How can I save result of each loop into variable and use the updated variable in the next run of the loop?

```
function toisto(t,a,o) {
//t = 5
//a = 200
//o is a function for halving
    for (var i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        var puolitustulo = o(a);
    }
    console.log(puolitustulo);
}
```

Comment: _"I'm new to JavaScript"_ - Then stay away from `var` and use `let` and `const` (which would also "solve" your problem, because it then would correctly throw an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem You need to "update" variable `a` inside the loop.

```
function toisto(t, a, o) {
//t = 5
//a = 200
//o is a function for halving
    for (let i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        //assign new value to the variable in each iteration
        a = o(a);
    }
    // variable a is available in this scope
    console.log(a);
}
```

Another important problem is scope, take a look at this article at MDN [var keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). As mentioned, using `let` and `const` instead of `var` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
function o(a){
    return a/2;    
}

function toisto(t,a,o) {
//You define and initialize variable before loop
let puolitustulo =0;
    for (let i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        puolitustulo= o(a);
        //You need to update your a to new value
        a=puolitustulo;
    }
    console.log(puolitustulo);
}


toisto(5,200,o);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have there, This will be my solution. Instead of declaring the new variable on the loop you can simply pass the **same variable (i.e. a)** and get the halves.
And to get the value of halves on each iteration simply, put the console output inside the for a loop.

```
function o(value)
{
    return value/2;
}


function toisto(t,a) {

    for (var i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        a = o(a);
      console.log(a);
    }
    
}

toisto(5,200);
```